# Getting error for radio button when input values are reset in Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

I have a form with input fields and a radio button. I am using a library which extends Form_validation class for resetting the input values, once form is submitted.

Code for  **MY_Form_validation.php**:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed.');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
{
    public function MY_Form_validation() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function unset_field_data()
    { 
        unset($this->_field_data); 
    }
}
```

and it is working well for all input fields other than radio button.

I am creating radio button as:

```
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('trailer', '1', TRUE); ?> />Yes
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="0" <?php echo set_radio('trailer', '0'); ?> />No
```

Since I want to reset the radio values upon form errors.

I have successfully submitted the form and the form is getting cleared. But I am getting error next to the radio button in the form.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: MY_Form_validation::$_field_data
Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
Line Number: 807
checked="checked" />
```

I think this is because, the code doesn't resets radio buttons.

Comment: It is a property of field. I followed this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802046/codeigniter-form-validation-how-to-unset-form-values-after-success

Answer (score 0):

change this function to

```
public function MY_Form_validation() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

to this

```
 function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```