# Taking Email and password Value Null

Tags: php, codeigniter

While Clicking on register button after form filling it shows the error that email address and password are empty, the front end script validates the email and password, the server side script has an issue. Please take a look.
Stackoverflow is asking me to add more details and I have no idea what else should I type to make it more detailed. So here I am typing the details with much detail.
Codeignator

View.php

```
<?php echo form_open('user/register'); ?>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Birth Date" class="textbox-n" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  name="birthday"> 


<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option selected="selected">--Gender--</option>
                                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                  </select>
<input type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password"   name="password" required>
<button type="submit">Register</button>
    php echo form_close(); ?><p>
```

User Controller

```
function register()
{

    $data['error'] = NULL;
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $config = array(
             array(
                'field' => 'fname',
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            ),
             array(
                'field' => 'lname',
                'label' => 'Last Name',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'number',
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|is_unique[users.number]',
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]',
            ),

            array(
                'field' => 'gender',
                'label' => 'Gender',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            ),
             array(
                'field' => 'birthday',
                'label' => 'Birth Date',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email',
            ),




        );
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['error'] = validation_errors();
        }
        else 
        {
.
.
.
Further registration Process
```

Comment: whats you route in routes.php ?

Comment: welcome is the route page in route.php

Comment: where you have registered your route **user/register** i am asking you about routes.php.

Comment: It's in the class user

Comment: This may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381910/3278639